# Selenium webdriver C#: Unable to identify button element inside form tag of HTML

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

[Full Html Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsIeD.png)[image]

**I need to click the button with the id(export_but)**

The HTML code of the form tag can be seen in the image, the form is popped up when I click on a button. , tried finding the element by XPath, CssSelector, Id etc all options available.

And also the popup is not an alert, so I tried

```
driver.SwitchTo().Alert()
```

It doesnt work.

Need help in identifying this element.

Comment: Show us the your code & html

Comment: Confirm is the from in new window or frame, If yes, you need to switch into that window/frame firstly, If not,  add some sleep before find the button

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: please check whether it's in iframe or not

Comment: Its not an iframe.
Form is popped up in a dialogue box. 
And I tried switching windows & iframes still doesnt work.
Giving sleep also doesn't work.
I am getting wait time out and element is not visible error.
Please see my code below:
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.LinkText(sLinkText)));
            IWebElement eElement = driver.FindElement(By.LinkTexT(sLinkText));
            eElement.Click();

Comment: The above code snipped is for LinkText, I also tried for XPath, css selector, id, class name etc. It doesn't work

Comment: @ShravanKoneru : the full html you have provided that start with HTML tag is in iframe ?

Comment: please use @ to comment , so that we can receive messages in inbox. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have provided and your question that *the form is popped up when you click on a button*, to identify the the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `<input>` element to be clickable and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategy* :

- *cssSelector* :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input.submit#export_but[value='Export']")));
  ```
- *xpath* :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@class='submit' and @id='export_but' and @value='Export']")));
  ```

---

### Update

As per your comment update as you are still unable to locate the element you can alternatively invoke the `ExpectedConditions` method [ElementIsVisible()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementIsVisible.htm) as follows :

- *cssSelector* :

  ```
  IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("input.submit#export_but[value='Export']")));
  element.Submit();
  ```
- *xpath* :

  ```
  IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//input[@class='submit' and @id='export_but' and @value='Export']")));
  element.Submit()
  ```

Comment: I have used webdriver wait as well and tried using XPath, CssSelector, Id. Its still not Identifying

Comment: @ShravanKoneru Update the question with a bit more of the `outerHTML`. Additionally traverse up the DOM in development console and try to observe if the element is within an `iframe`

Comment: There is an iframe in the DOM but this webElement doesnt fall under that iframe. I have added a new image(Full Html Code) of the entire html. Please check

Comment: Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: Can you update the question with text based HTML for further analysis?